# Unsupported post request. Object with ID '###' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We're attempting to use the Facebook nodejs SDK to create and manage ad campaigns, ad sets, ads, etc. We followed the guide in the Quickstart link of the Meta for Developers Marketing API section. Our Business account has an Admin System User with permissions scoped to the required marketing scopes and that user has been added to all accounts in the accounts section.

When we debug the access token, we can see it has the scopes

[image: Access token scopes]

When we inspect the access token with https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/adaccounts?access_token=, we can see the two ad account IDs (a sandbox ID and a production ID)

[image: Access token ad account access]

And when we inspect the access token with https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/permissions?access_token=, we get

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "permission": "read_insights",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "ads_management",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "ads_read",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "public_profile",
         "status": "granted"
      }
   ]
}
```

As far as I can tell, everything appears to be set up correctly. But whenever we make an API call we get the "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'XXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22) error (where XXX is our sandbox ad account id).

And to confuse matters even more, when trying to submit a bug to Facebook, it says that both the sandbox and production ad account IDs are invalid. That's strange because that ad account is the one we use to manually create ads on production, is the same ad account ID that is shown in the Meta Ad Manager site, and is the same ad account ID that we just received a payment summary for from Meta.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been blocked on this for 3 days now.